# SQL Server and Operating System Combination Sacrifices

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Since most responders like to understand why the question is being asked, I offer this brief preface. . .

I am in the process of preparing a version migration document for a state government agency.  The migration will be from Microsoft SQL Server 2000 (MSSQL2000) production environments to a later version, i.e., Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP3 (MSSQL2005), Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP1 (MSSQL2008), or Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (R2) (Kilimanjaro).  The agency is an Oracle shop.  The current in situ enterprise-wide Windows Server operating system is Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (R2) Enterprise Edition SP2.  There are no plans to move to Windows Server 2008 in the immediate future -- the server unit is not even experimenting with Windows Server 2008 as of this date.

*the question:*  What sacrifices (performance, features, etc.) are you making in running MSSQL2008 or Kilimanjaro on Microsoft Windows Server 2003 (R2) Enterprise Edition SP2?

Thanks in advance to all who respond!

Answer (score 2):

None that I know of.  I don't think I've heard of any disadvantages of pairing SQL2008 with any relatively recent versions of Windows (as long as you're on a supported service pack), and we have SQL2008 running on Windows 2003 at my company with no problems.